# Can I stop other recursion tree branches from executing?

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am given a vector of integers and a sum, and if that sum can be generated from any combination of the elements in that vector, I need to return that combination. If more than one such combinations is possible, I may return any one.

For example,

sum = 20, vector = {6,25,8}, we may print 8 6 6 as 8+6+6 = 20

sum = 10, vector = {4,6,7}, we may print 6 4 as 6+4 = 10

sum = 15, vector = {8,4,5}, we may print 5 5 5 as 5+5+5 = 15

Problem : the last two examples above work fine, but the first one doesn't. The reason being that if you draw the recursion tree for the first example then as per my code, you get `flag` variable true because there exist more than one base case of `targetSum` = 0 under the same parent node. The last example therefore prints 8 6 6 8 6.

My question is that, since I only need to print any possible combination that adds up to the `targetSum`, can I skip over other branches of the recursion tree ? Basically once we hit the base case of `targetSum` = 0 we go up the tree and print out the sequence ? Is that possible ? (I have tried to use `stackCount` for this purpose, but it only prevents the right side children of the root node from executing if a sequence that sums up to `targetSum` has been found.) If not, then please let me know how or what to modify in this code so that it works correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

bool howSum(int &targetSum, vector<int> &elementVector, vector<int> &howSumVector, map<int, bool> &memo, int &stackCount) {
    stackCount++;
    if (memo.find(targetSum) != memo.end())
        return memo[targetSum];
    else if (targetSum == 0)
        return true;
    else if (targetSum < 0)
        return false;
    else {
        for (auto i : elementVector) {
            int remainder = targetSum - i;
            bool flag = howSum(remainder, elementVector, howSumVector, memo, stackCount);
            stackCount--;
            if (flag) {
                    howSumVector.push_back(i);
                    memo[targetSum] = true;
            } else if(memo.find(targetSum) == memo.end())
                memo[targetSum] = false;
            if(stackCount == 1 && !howSumVector.empty())
                return true;
        }
        return memo[targetSum];
    }
}

int main() {
    int stackCount = 0;
    int sum = 20; // test cases 20,10,15
    map<int, bool> memo;
    vector<int> elements = {6,25,8}; // test cases {6,25,8},{4,6,7},{8,4,5}
    vector<int> workingBench = {};
    howSum(sum, elements, workingBench, memo, stackCount);
    for (auto i : workingBench)
        cout << i << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to end the recursion when you find a match, in this case that's when `flag == true`.

```
if (flag) {
    howSumVector.push_back(i);
    memo[targetSum] = true;
    return true; // We found a match! Stop searching!
}
```

**Edit:**

You are not using memo correctly. Since you only want one of the possible solutions, you don't need to keep track of if a certain combination works.

What you want is to keep track of if you've had the same remainder before. If you did, you can simply abort the search right there.

If the target is `20` and you have some combination of numbers that give you a remainder of 5, it doesn't matter what combination of numbers got us there.

Let's say we couldn't reach the target from 15, then if we somehow get to 15 again with a different combination of number we already know we can never reach the target from 15, so we can just abort the search there.

And if we could have reached the target from 15, we have already found a solution and the recursion has already ended, so we don't care about that outcome either.

Here's a modified complete example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

bool howSum(int targetSum, const vector<int> &elementVector, vector<int> &howSumVector, set<int> &memo) {
    if (memo.find(targetSum) != memo.end()) {
        return false;
    }
    memo.insert(targetSum);

    if (targetSum == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (targetSum < 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (auto i : elementVector) {
            bool flag = howSum(targetSum - i, elementVector, howSumVector, memo);
            if (flag) {
                howSumVector.push_back(i);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    int sum = 20; //20,10,15
    set<int> memo;
    vector<int> elements = {6,25,8}; // {6,25,8},{4,6,7},{8,4,5}
    vector<int> workingBench = {};
    howSum(sum, elements, workingBench, memo);
    if (workingBench.empty())
        cout << "not possible";
    else
        for (auto i : workingBench)
            cout << i << " ";
}
```

Some other notes. I changed to pass `targetSum` by value. You never modify it so passing by reference is pointless.

I also changed `elementVector` to be passed by `const &`, since we don't want to modify it. It's just a good habit.

Comment: Interesting, I don't need to keep track of stack count anymore as well.

Comment: @DivyanshuVarma I made some edits to address you use of `memo` and a couple of other details.

Comment: "You are not using `memo` correctly." For this exact problem statement, I agree this modified solution of yours is simple and elegant. However, after this problem statement my next task is to find the smallest possible combination that can lead to `targetSum`. So probably I wasn't thinking clearly about this problem statement, rather thinking about the next one !

Comment: "I changed to pass `targetSum` by value. You never modify it so passing by reference is pointless." Won't that mean copying that value over and over again (unnecessary time + memory consumption )?

Comment: "I also changed `elementVector` to be passed by `const &`, since we don't want to modify it. It's just a good habit." Yes, I agree and I will take care of that now.

Comment: @DivyanshuVarma I does mean copying the value every time, but passing by reference is not free either. It costs something, and in most cases it would be equivalent to passing a pointer. A pointer is on most modern systems bigger then the size of an `int`, but will in most practical situations be no difference in performance. It could potentially be cheaper to pass by value, since sometime the compiler will need to dereference a pointer to get the value of a reference, but if you pass by value that will never be an issue.

Comment: It's not all that uncommon to see people write special overloads to handle primitive types differently then classes, since passing them by value can be a performance increase and never costs more then passing by reference.

Answer (score 0):

My final code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

bool howSum(int &targetSum, vector<int> &elementVector, vector<int> &howSumVector, map<int, bool> &memo) {
    if (memo.find(targetSum) != memo.end())
        return memo[targetSum];
    else if (targetSum == 0)
        return true;
    else if (targetSum < 0)
        return false;
    else {
        for (auto i : elementVector) {
            int remainder = targetSum - i;
            bool flag = howSum(remainder, elementVector, howSumVector, memo);
            if (flag) {
                howSumVector.push_back(i);
                memo[targetSum] = true;
                return true;
            } else if (memo.find(targetSum) == memo.end()) // if targetSum is NOT in memo
                memo[targetSum] = false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    int sum = 20; //20,10,15
    map<int, bool> memo;
    vector<int> elements = {6,25,8}; // {6,25,8},{4,6,7},{8,4,5}
    vector<int> workingBench = {};
    howSum(sum, elements, workingBench, memo);
    if (workingBench.empty())
        cout << "not possible";
    else
        for (auto i : workingBench)
            cout << i << " ";
}
```